# How to find a duplicate in a list without using set in python?

Tags: python

I know that we can use the set in python to find if there is any duplicate in a list. I was just wondering, if we can find a duplicate in a list without using set.

Say, my list is

```
a=['1545','1254','1545']
```

then how to find a duplicate?

Comment: Do you want to find if there any duplicates exist or get a list of duplicates or the first duplicate we can find?

Comment: existence of duplicates is enough.

Comment: Any reason you can't use a set?

Comment: I wanted to explore the problem from an iteration point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> lis = []
>>> a=['1545','1254','1545']
>>> for i in a:
...     if i not in lis:
...         lis.append(i)
... 
>>> lis
['1545', '1254']
>>> set(a)
set(['1254', '1545'])
```

Comment: He doesn't want to use `set` :)

Comment: i get that i just showed that my answer gives the same output as set does.

Answer (score 2):

```
a=['1545','1254','1545']
from collections import Counter
print [item for item, count in Counter(a).items() if count != 1]
```

**Output**

```
['1545']
```

This solution runs in O(N). This will be a huge advantage if the list used has a lot of elements.

If you just want to find if the list has duplicates, you can simply do

```
a=['1545','1254','1545']
from collections import Counter
print any(count != 1 for count in Counter(a).values())
```

As [@gnibbler suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925497/how-to-find-a-duplicate-in-a-list-without-using-set-in-python/21925540?noredirect=1#comment33210647_21925540), this would be the practically fastest solution

```
from collections import defaultdict
def has_dup(a):
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for item in a:
        result[item] += 1
        if result[item] > 1:
            return True
    else:
        return False

a=['1545','1254','1545']
print has_dup(a)
```

Comment: [`Counter(a).most_common()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) gives you more common elements first. The method also accept optional `n` (number). `any(count != 1 for count in Counter(a).values())` can be replace with `any(count != 1 for count in Counter(a).most_common(1))`, or even shorter: `Counter(a).most_common(1)[0][1] > 1` (assuming `a` is not empty)

Comment: Problem with the Counter is that it can't shortcircuit. Since just existance is enough, you should stop when the first count hits 2. bring on defaultdict answer.

Comment: @falsetru But to get `most_common`, it should be sorting internally, right? That makes it O(NlogN) :(

Comment: Ah, you're right. I thought `Counter` use heap queue interanlly, but it does not.

Comment: @gnibbler Included the `defaultdict` version :)

Answer (score 1):

use `list.count`:

```
In [309]: a=['1545','1254','1545']
     ...: a.count('1545')>1
Out[309]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`list.count`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes#common-sequence-operations):

```
>>> a = ['1545','1254','1545']
>>> any(a.count(x) > 1 for x in a) # To check whether there's any duplicate
True

>>> # To retrieve any single element that is duplicated
>>> next((x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1), None)
'1545'

# To get duplicate elements (used set literal!)
>>> {x for x in a if a.count(x) > 1}
set(['1545'])
```

Answer (score 1):

sort the list and check that the next value is not equal to the last one..

```
a.sort()
last_x = None
for x in a:
    if x == last_x:
       print "duplicate: %s" % x
       break # existence of duplicates is enough

    last_x = x
```

This should be O(n log n) which is slower for big n than the Counter solution (but counter uses a dict under the hood.. which is not too dissimilar from a set really).

An alternative is to insert the elements and keep the list sorted.. see the bisect module.  It makes your inserts slower but your check for duplicates fast.

Comment: This pattern can be simplified by `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: The only reason this is probably the best answer is that the only reason not to use set is because of memory usage. This gets around that.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann, no itertools.groupby only groups consecutive items. It's nothing like a set. SQL and Ruby's groupbys are another thing altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If this is homework, your teacher is probably asking for the hideously inefficient `.count()` style answer.

In practice using a `dict` is your next best bet if `set` is disallowed.

```
>>> a = ['1545','1254','1545']
>>> D = {}
>>> for i in a:
...     if i in D:
...         print "duplicate", i
...         break
...     D[i] = i
... else:
...     print "no duplicate"
... 
duplicate 1545
```

Here is a version using groupby which is still much better that the `.count()` method

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> a = ['1545','1254','1545']
>>> next(k for k, g in groupby(sorted(a)) if sum(1 for i in g) > 1)
'1545'
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for working on this problem. I also got to learn a lot from different answers. This is how I have answered:

```
a=['1545','1254','1545']
d=[]
duplicates=False
for i in a:
    if i not in d:
        d.append(i)
        if len(d)<len(a):
            duplicates=True
        else:
            duplicates=False
print(duplicates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using sets...

```py
original = ['1545','1254','1545']

# Non-duplicated elements
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(original) if i == original.index(x)]
['1545', '1254']

# Duplicated elements
>>> [x for i, x in enumerate(original) if i != original.index(x)]
['1545']
```